# Fast way of crossing strings in a list

Tags: python, list, concatenation

If have a list like so:

```
shops=['A','B','C','D']
```

And would like to create the following new lists (I cross each element with every other and create a string where first part is alphanumerically before the second):

```
['A-B', 'A-C', 'A-D']

['A-B', 'B-C', 'B-D']

['A-C', 'B-C', 'C-D']

['A-D', 'B-D', 'C-D']
```

I have something like this:

```
for a in shops:
    cons = []
    for b in shops:
        if a!=b:
            con = [a,b]
            con = sorted(con, key=lambda x: float(x))
            cons.append(con[0]+'-'+con[1])
    print(cons)
```

However, this is pretty slow for large lists (e.g. 1000 where I have 1000*999*0.5 outputs). I was looking for a more efficient way of doing this?

I could have used an if-else clause for the sort e.g.

```
for a in shops:
    cons = []
    for b in shops:
        if a<b:
            cons.append(a+"-"+b)
        elif a>b:
            cons.append(b+"-"+a)
    print(cons)
```

Which, I haven't timed yet - however I thought the main slow-down was the double for-loop

Comment: Why not `('A_B', 'A_C', 'B_C')`?

Comment: `key=lambda x: float(x)` is the same -- just slower -- as `key=float`

Comment: I don't thing you can get the overall complexity of this algorithms down, as you have to generate all those combinations. You only can do micro-tuning (as in not defining unnecessary lambdas). However: What do you need those combinations for in the first place? Maybe there's a better way, e.g. just generating the combinations, or without the sorting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a nested list-comprehension with some additional checks:

```
>>> shops=['A','B','C','D']
>>> [["-".join((min(a,b), max(a,b))) for b in shops if b != a] for a in shops]
[['A-B', 'A-C', 'A-D'],
 ['A-B', 'B-C', 'B-D'],
 ['A-C', 'B-C', 'C-D'],
 ['A-D', 'B-D', 'C-D']]
```

Note that this will probably not be much faster than your code, as you still have to generate all those combinations. In practice, you could make it a generator expression, so the elements are not generated all at once but only "as needed":

```
gen = (["-".join((min(a,b), max(a,b))) for b in shops if b != a] for a in shops)
for item in gen:
    print(item)
```

---

Update: I did some timing analysis using IPython's `%timeit`. Turns out your second implementation is the fastest. Tested with a list of 100 strings (`map(str, range(100))`) and after turning each of the methods into generators.

```
In [32]: %timeit list(test.f1())         # your first implementation
100 loops, best of 3: 13.5 ms per loop

In [33]: %timeit list(test.f2())         # your second implementation
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.63 ms per loop

In [34]: %timeit list(test.g())          # my implementation
100 loops, best of 3: 3.49 ms per loop
```

You can speed it up by using a simple `if/else` instead of `min/max`, as in your 2nd implementation, then they are about equally fast.

```
(["-".join((a,b) if a < b else (b,a)) for b in shops if b != a] for a in shops)
```

Comment: Thanks very much! What is the difference between using a generator expression or using a function and returning with yield? I've generally done the former.

Comment: @mptevsion They are roughly equivalent. A generator expression is to a function with yield as a list comprehension is to a function returning a list.

Comment: @mptevsion `yield` is more general. It's an expression and you can pass values into the function by using the `send` method. This cannot be done in a generator expression. Try it: `def f(): x=yield 0; yield x` then do `a = f(); next(a); a.send(1); next(a)`.

Answer (score 4):

If the list is sorted and there are no duplicates, you can keep track of your position in the list to avoid having to do comparisons to get the order.

```
from itertools import chain, islice

combos = []
for i, s in enumerate(shops):
    combo = ['{0}-{1}'.format(a, b) for a, b in chain(
        ((c, s) for c in islice(shops, None, i),
        ((s, c) for c in islice(shops, i+1))]
    combos.append(combo)
```

EDIT: updated to use generators

Comment: I thought that creating all those temporary lists would be horribly slow, but (when converted to a generator)  this is about as fast as OP's second implementations or my generator. However, for large lists I seem to get a different result. For `shops=map(str, range(10))` the results are equal, but with `map(str, range(100))` the result of yours differs, can't tell how, though...

Comment: @tobias_k: This assumes the list is sorted. When you have numbers >=10 as strings, the shops aren't correctly sorted at the start anymore. (I had the same idea, but Brendan beat me to it :)

Comment: @AleksiTorhamo You are right, just checked: The difference comes from the shops being sorted differently in our implementations.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks for the idea, just updated to use generators.  Now it doesn't have to create that second temporary list.

Comment: Actually, that's not what I meant... you are already creating temporary lists with `shops[:i]` and `shops[i+1:]`, and I made it a generator by replacing the last line with `yield combo` (assuming it is inside a function).

Comment: @tobias_k Ah, yes, wasn't even thinking about those.  More generators.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you said:

> I cross each element with every other and create a string where first
>   part is alphanumerically before the second

You can use 2 combination like following:

```
>>> form itertools import combinations
>>> list(combinations(['_'.join(i) for i in combinations(shops,2)],3)
... )
[('A_B', 'A_C', 'A_D'), ('A_B', 'A_C', 'B_C'), ('A_B', 'A_C', 'B_D'), ('A_B', 'A_C', 'C_D'), ('A_B', 'A_D', 'B_C'), ('A_B', 'A_D', 'B_D'), ('A_B', 'A_D', 'C_D'), ('A_B', 'B_C', 'B_D'), ('A_B', 'B_C', 'C_D'), ('A_B', 'B_D', 'C_D'), ('A_C', 'A_D', 'B_C'), ('A_C', 'A_D', 'B_D'), ('A_C', 'A_D', 'C_D'), ('A_C', 'B_C', 'B_D'), ('A_C', 'B_C', 'C_D'), ('A_C', 'B_D', 'C_D'), ('A_D', 'B_C', 'B_D'), ('A_D', 'B_C', 'C_D'), ('A_D', 'B_D', 'C_D'), ('B_C', 'B_D', 'C_D')]
>>>
```

At first you can use a combination within a list comprehension to create the ordered pairs and concatenate them using `str.join`. Then use another combinations to create the trinal sets.

Comment: This doesn't appear to extend well to the case of 6 elements in the list.

Comment: As I understand the question, the first sublist should have A in each combination, the second B, then C and D, each with each of the other letters, sorted alphabetically.

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, that's what is clear in expected output, but not in what OP has said.

Comment: @Alexander I know, I just gave an answer based on OP's request.

Comment: The output is not identical to the specification, even after correcting `form` to `from`.